# nestJS "socket.io-redis": "6.0.1"

Tags: redis, nestjs

**according to the documentation**
TypeScript
// npm i -D @types/redis

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from 'socket.io-redis';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

const io = new Server(8080);
const pubClient = new RedisClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

io.adapter(createAdapter({ pubClient, subClient }));
```

**I create redis adapter**

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from 'socket.io-redis';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(port: number, options?: any): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    const pubClient = new RedisClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
    server.adapter(createAdapter({ pubClient, subClient }));
    return server;
  }
}
```

**after i use dispatch this.appGateway.server.emit('test', 'hello');**

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Encoder.encode (/home/test/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:135:5)
    at RedisAdapter.broadcast (/home/test/node_modules/socket.io-redis/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js:102:45)
    at RedisAdapter.broadcast (/home/test/node_modules/socket.io-redis/dist/index.js:267:15)
    at Namespace.emit (/home/test/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:234:16)
    at Server.<computed> [as emit] (/home/test/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:505:29)
```

**my gateWay**

```
import { OnGatewayConnection,  WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AppGateway.name);

  @WebSocketServer()
  server;
  
  handleConnection(client): any {
    this.logger.log('new user connected...');
    client.emit('connection', 'Succesfuly connected');
  }

}
```

**help please solve the problem**

Answer (score 2):

`socket.io-redis` ^6 uses socket.io version 3 which is not yet supported by Nest. There's an open issue about it [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676) and it's set to be ready for Nest v8