# RedisIoAdapter has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nestjs

I'am trying to have socket.io-redis as dispatcher after implementing RedisIoAdapter how it has been described in https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import * as redisIoAdapter from 'socket.io-redis';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(port: number, options?: any): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    const redisAdapter = redisIoAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });

    server.adapter(redisAdapter);
    return server;
  }
}
```

getting error `redisIoAdapter` This expression is not callable.

```
"socket.io-redis": "^6.0.1"
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.6.4",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^7.6.4",
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the reason for the error. Just downgrade the **Redis** socket package to `5.0` and it'll be good to go.

Refer: [Nextjs-Socket-Io-Redis-6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134378/nestjs-socket-io-redis-6-0-1)